# php-ews folders do not match php-ews code at all

Tags: exchange-server-2010, php-ews

Installed `php-ews` using composer:

```
{
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "prefer-stable": true,
  "require":
  {
    "php-ews/php-ews": "dev-master"
  }
}
```

The installation passed fine.

Made this simple request in my project code:

```
require_once 'composer/vendor/autoload.php';
use \php-ews\php-ews\src\Client;

$host = 'my.server.co.il';
$username = 'user@server.co.il';
$password = 'myPass';
$version = Client::VERSION_2010;

$client = new Client($host, $username, $password, $version);
```

But the PHP doesn't accept hyphens (-) in its `use` command path, 
I got the error:

> PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting ',' or ';' in /var/www/html

Then I noticed, the paths of the `use` phrases in all the code files of the `php-ews` project, do not match the project files that where installed using the composer at all. For example, in the *create.php* file there are `use` phrases:

```
use \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Client;
use \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Request\CreateItemType;

use \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\ArrayType\NonEmptyArrayOfAllItemsType;
use \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\ArrayType\NonEmptyArrayOfAttendeesType;

use \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Enumeration\BodyTypeType;
use \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Enumeration\CalendarItemCreateOrDeleteOperationType;
use \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Enumeration\ResponseClassType;
use \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Enumeration\RoutingType;
```

The above paths do not even exist in the project at all.... 
The project files and folders that the composer installed, they do not match the code `use` and `require` phrases inside of them.

Did I make the wrong installation?
is there other way to use the *composer.json* file so I can install the project right, without hyphens (php-ews) in the directories?

`php-ews` Version installed:

```
"packages": [{
  "name": "jamesiarmes/php-ntlm",
  "version": "1.0.0-beta.1",
  "extra": {
    "branch-alias": {
      "dev-master": "1.0.x-dev"
    }
  }
}]
```

Linux Centos 7
PHP version: 5.4.16
Microsoft Exchange version: 2010

Answer (score 0):

installation seems correct.
    `require != use`
use is a namespace, this on is defined in the Client.php, which is autoloaded.
client.php line 6:
   `namespace jamesiarmes\PhpEws;`